# Android kills and restart my service when I swipe the application in the recent app view

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-lifecycle

I'm creating a GPS logger as a `Service`, I need to control it from an `Activity` i.e: Start/Stop, set the frequency, ... , but would like to keep on running the logger after the ui (`Activity`) is destroyed (`onDestroy` has been called).

To do so, I have an activity that call `startService` when it's created and `bindService` to the GPS logger service `onStart` and `unbindService` `onStop`.

From what I understand, the `Service` and the `Activity` runs in the same thread.

The logger start correctly, the bind/unbind works fine, but if I kill the activity in the recent list, a new process with a new pid start and the service gets recreated... This service does not know about the settings the user gave to the previous instance.

The next time I start the ui (`Activity`), it runs in the same process as the `Service` that got started just after killing the last ui instance.

I know the `Service` get restarted because I return `START_STICKY` in `onStartCommand`, but why/how can I avoid it being stopped in the first place ?

Comment: Swiping out of recents kills the entire process.  This has been covered here many times before.

Comment: So I should run the Service is a separed process or have the whole config in an Intent ?

Comment: Not exactly : 
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=53313
The service is killed when you get a broadcast information and the app is swiped away from the recent app list.